# Can't access Jenkins (Docker container) web address (172.17.0.2) from MacOs

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-for-mac

I pulled `jenkins` `image` from `docker hub` and try to run with the following command:

```
docker run jenkins
```

or

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins
```

Then I'm inspecting running jenkins: `docker inspect [container id]`, `networks` node in output says that `ip address` is `172.17.0.2` but when I type in browser `172.17.0.2:8080` it can't be reached.. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use **localhost:8080** or your **mac-machine-IP-address:8080** from the browser.

The 172.17.0.2 is docker machine IP address which is not accessible from outside.
Please let me know if it's still not working.

Thanks.

Comment: @Arkadi the reason why your approach didn't work is described [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds). There are some network limitations for `docker-for-mac`.

Comment: localhost:8080 doesn't work for me. I get a 'can't open the page' error'. any idea why ?

Comment: @wildthing81 - Which command you are using to run Docker containers? Please check your exporting port numbers and also can you please send an output of "docker ps -a" command.

Comment: thanks.I fixed the problem.I was mapping 8080 to a different container port than 8080.

Comment: @wildthing81 I was also doing the same thing accidentally. Can someone explain why the internal docker container port has to be 8080 and not something else? It's more a question of curiosity